# Handling pop-up in android app using Appium

Tags: java, android, selenium-webdriver, appium

i am using Appium(java) to  test android app that contains pop-up window ,(pop-up appears after clicking a button..)

the popup compose from :

Framelayout with resource-id : android:id/content
LinearLayout with resource-id :android:id/parentPanel
LinearLayout (contain 2 buttons) with resource-id :android:id/buttonPanel

i want to press 1 of the buttons inside it ...
i tried verity of options that i found on the web  , but nothing works 
[image]

Comment: show what u do in ur code.....

Comment: String  handle= driver.getWindowHandle();
driver.switchTo().window(handle);
                            WebElement
 bDenoiseDialogDenoise = driver.findElement(By.id("com.mv4d.oxalis:id/button1"));
    bDenoiseDialogDenoise.click();

Answer (score 1):

you can use self.driver.find_element_by_name("text to be clicked")

Comment: you can use id of Ok button, or u can create an xpath with Ok text